# Is there a “function size profiler” out there for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, profiling

I'm developing a small framework filled with various utilities--the smaller the better, so that it doesn't bloat the size of downloadable programs that use it. Is there any tool to reveal the size in bytes of my methods, interfaces and classes?

(I've been removing various classes to see how much the file size changes, but for some reason the DLL is always a multiple of 4 KB so I can't tell precisely how big a given class is, let alone a method. Anyway, that approach is a pain in the ass because when I remove one piece, I have to also remove any bits of code that depend on it.)

I asked this question earlier [for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051597/is-there-a-function-size-profiler-out-there) (conclusion was: no, but in Linux there's a useful shell command).

Comment: You want to _profile_ static code? As in the physical size, in bytes, of the source - and not the amount of memory used at runtime? Visual Studio itself would tell you `x characters` per file.

Comment: You shouldn't be that worried about the size of the code, if you write code that runs fast and doesn't explode in size, that is usually far above what the average programmer does.

Comment: The size of the source files includes documentation (which is in places very large and in other places missing entirely), and doesn't give me a clue about what takes up the most space in the binary representation. For instance I have a lot of small classes and helper methods; I'm curious how big a series of small helpers is, relative to (say) the size of a single large method. Some code uses the ?: operator a lot, but that probably doesn't save much binary space over code that uses an eight-line if (...) { x = ... } else { x = ... } construct.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the file doesn't change size when you edit things is because each section of the PE format is aligned to certain boundaries. (Eg, the .text section will usually begin at offset 0x1000), and the other sections are aligned, depending on the size of their content. Between them is padding of '\0', so that space will effectively be eliminated when the file is compressed by an installer.

It's doubtful that you need to worry about the size of your methods, as they will usually be in the magnitude of tens of bytes. The metadata for each method takes up more space than that. You'd save more space by shortening variable names and string literals than you would rewriting methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try reflection. There is a method in MethodInfo class to get the MSIL representation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody.aspx

Comment: But that only gives you a tiny portion of the method; like Mark said in his answer, metadata is often far larger than actual function data.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Reflector shows that information (when decompiling to MSIL, each instruction is shown with a "line number" that is the offset, in bytes, from the beginning of the method)

Comment: @qwertie: Maybe writing a plugin for [Simple Assembly Explorer](http://code.google.com/p/simple-assembly-explorer/) would get you the information you want.  That way you can reuse someone else's known working metadata parser.  If the plugin interface doesn't give access to the needed information, you can modify the metadata parser itself, since the code is open source.

Answer (score -1):

Windows

```
ildasm
```

Mono

```
monodis
```

Will disassemble the assemblies (or parts of them) via the commandline

Comment: Which leads me to a table of sizes for the binary representation how?